# Query To show Columns to Rows in SQL Server 2008.

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have to write a query which is joining 3 tables. i have following tables.

```
    Table Case
    CaseID  CaseType   CaseStatus
    001       1         2        
    002       2         1        
    003       3         4        

    Table Case Type
    TypeID    Name   
    1       Fraud            
    2       Duplicate    
    3       Other
```

and finally Case Status

```
    StatusID      Name   
    1             Resolved             
    2             Pending     
    3             Waiting
```

i need result like this

```
    Type          NumberofCase   Resolved    Pending   Waiting
    Fraud         1              1            0         0
    Duplicate     2              0            1         1
    Other         4              2            1         1
```

What i need to do if i don't want to use temporary tables. How this can be accomplished by Col-case or any other method.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `join` and conditional aggregation:

```
select ct.Name as "Type", count(*) as NumberOfCase,
       sum(case when cs.Name = 'Resolved' then 1 else 0 end) as Resolved,
       sum(case when cs.Name = 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) as Pending,
       sum(case when cs.Name = 'Waiting' then 1 else 0 end) as Waiting
from "case" c join
     CaseType ct
     on c.CaseType = ct.TypeId join
     CaseStatus cs
     on c.CaseStatus = cs.StatusId
group by ct.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative approach would be to use

```
Pivot() Over()
```